# countunique with filter based on multiple criteria Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Hello I have a problem when I try to combine count and filter. I have been struggling with this for a long time please help me.

What I want to do : 
I want to count unique dates for a specific press machine between my selected dates range. 
For example, between dates 12-02 to 12-22 press 100 should count as 3

Please see the spreadsheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KhIst0MKX6-K3pTwmOr_76gueDEJnB6Hrb4rIrkwBzY/edit#gid=600239356

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share this spreadsheet (rather then just a picture of it ?) ?

Comment: Yes I can! Thank you!  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KhIst0MKX6-K3pTwmOr_76gueDEJnB6Hrb4rIrkwBzY/edit#gid=600239356

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want. I works off the Starting Date and Ending Date on your Pressrm OEE sheet.You should be able to put the formula on any sheet in your workbook.

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(filter('1st Pressrm data'!$B$2:$B$11,'1st Pressrm data'!$B$2:$B$11>='Pressrm OEE'!A2,'1st Pressrm data'!$B$2:$B$11<='Pressrm OEE'!A4,'1st Pressrm data'!$D$2:$D$11="Press 100"))
```

If you data is going to be expanding to more rows use this.

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(iferror(filter('1st Pressrm data'!$B$2:$B,'1st Pressrm data'!$B$2:$B>='Pressrm OEE'!A2,'1st Pressrm data'!$B$2:$B<='Pressrm OEE'!A4,'1st Pressrm data'!$D$2:$D="Press 100")))
```

Comment: Thanks thats awesome! its so weird because I worked off cell D2 and E2..... it did not work for me, I guess it is some kind of format thing.